# Stuck with PHP redirection to URL based on input

Tags: php

I'm building a referral-based site and only want it to be accessed by people who enter a valid referral code. The landing page will just be a simple input box and a go button. Once they type in a correct code, they will then be redirected to a certain URL depending on what code they type in. Otherwise they will get an error message.

I have written the code all in one page using HTML and PHP.

It works as planned except for one thing... regardless of what is typed they just get redirected to the home page. Even if you type nothing you end up on the home page.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong, or perhaps a better way would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: landingpage1 
*/
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['suche'])) {
    if ($_POST['suche'] == ‘REFERRAL3’) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = “MY-URL-1”
            </script>';
    } elseif ($_POST['suche'] == ‘REFERRAL1’) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = “MY-URL-2”
            </script>';
    } elseif ($_POST['suche'] == ‘REFERRAL2’) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = “MY-URL-3”
            </script>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error: You put in the wrong code.';
    }
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>

<div id="page" class="page">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Enter referral code: <input name="suche" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use php's `header()` function for redirect? It's mutch saver too. Beside this, your error message only show whenever `$_POST['suche']` is set. You can move it just after the `if`, because `header` will redirect otherwise.

```
if (isset($_POST['suche'])) {
    if ($_POST['suche'] == "REFERRAL3") {
        header("Location: MY-URL-1");
    } elseif ($_POST['suche'] == "REFERRAL1") {
        header("Location: MY-URL-2");
    } elseif ($_POST['suche'] == "REFERRAL2") {
        header("Location: MY-URL-3");
    }

    echo 'Error: You put in the wrong code.';
}
```

Or use `switch` instead of many `if`. It's better to maintain.

```
if (isset($_POST['suche'])) {
    switch( $_POST['suche'] ) {
        case "REFERRAL1":
            header("Location: MY-URL-1");
            break;

        case "REFERRAL2":
            header("Location: MY-URL-2");
            break;

        case "REFERRAL3":
            header("Location: MY-URL-3");
            break;

        default:
            echo 'Error: You put in the wrong code.';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not too sure what you mean by header () function. I'm fairly new to PHP.

I just typed in your code between the <?php and ?> tags but it does the exact same thing! :(

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it makes a difference but this is within a Wordpres theme. 

I just created a blank page template called landingpage1 and this is the code in it.

Comment: I tried the switch code also, but has the same effect. However the "Error: You put in the wrong code." is displayed above the search box before even typing anything.

Comment: @ChrisPaton `header()` is php function that redirect one page to another same as window.location.. for more info pls google it

Comment: Ahh okay, then the `isset` is correct for you. I was thinking your used a seperate php file. I've edited my answer for this. @ChrisPaton

Comment: change `<input type="submit" value="Go">` to `<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Go">` and `(isset($_POST['suche']))` to `(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: I changed all this and now an incorrect code take me to the "this page cannot be displayed" and correct code takes me to a syntax error on line 44.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **header('Location: http://www.example.com/');** for redirect in php
just like this

```
if ($_POST['suche'] == ‘REFERRAL3’) {
    header('Location: MY-URL-1');
}
```

Comment: Yeah tried that, doesn't work. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

In your code `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` will return index.php, Your form doesn't submitted to the same template file. It is submitted to index.php.

In order to stay on the same page on submit you just fill in `action=""` into the form tag.

Change

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: I just made this change and it just removed the input box altogether?

Comment: Dont delete the line.. just delete `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` this one from action property..

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, got the text box back but still not working properly. So just to confirm this should be the only change from the original code I posted? Because I made a few adjustments from other comments.

Comment: I just made the change as you mentioned to the original code and it's gotten me half way there.

Now instead of directing any input to the home page, it's now rejecting all inputs and generating the "Error: You put in the wrong code." message.

Comment: Now. your redirecting issue is solved. Your new problem is in the if - else part.. Please check the values you are comparing in if - else part. use quotes. eg: `if ($_POST['suche'] == "REFERRAL3")`